# pip3 version installing package into different directory

Tags: python, pip, homebrew

I recently set up a new version of Python 3.11 in my system using Homebrew, the pip3 that came with it seems to be installing into the wrong target (numpy package is used as an example):

```
python3.11 -m pip install numpy
Collecting numpy
  Using cached numpy-1.24.1-cp311-cp311-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (19.8 MB)
Installing collected packages: numpy
Successfully installed numpy-1.24.1
WARNING: Target directory /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/numpy-1.24.1.dist-info already exists. Specify --upgrade to force replacement.
WARNING: Target directory /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/numpy already exists. Specify --upgrade to force replacement.
WARNING: Target directory /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/bin already exists. Specify --upgrade to force replacement.
```

The Python3 pip list and uninstall command shows that the package is uninstalled:

```
python3.11 -m pip list
Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        22.3.1
setuptools 65.6.3
wheel      0.38.4

---------- ----------------- ----------------- ----------------- ----------------- -----------
python3.11 -m pip uninstall numpy
WARNING: Skipping numpy as it is not installed.
```

The locations of my Python 3.11 and pip3.11 are:

```
which python3.11
/usr/local/bin/python3.11
---------- ----------------- ----------------- ----------------- ----------------- -----------
which pip3.11
/usr/local/bin/pip3.11
---------- ----------------- ----------------- ----------------- ----------------- -----------
pip3.11 --version
pip 22.3.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip (python 3.11)
```

I've tried installing different versions of Python (3.9 & 3.10) but all of it suffers from the error shown, the pip3 command keeps targeting the wrong directory.

I've also tried the following command:

```
python3.11 -m pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pip
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but I have had nothing but trouble with homebrew installed Python interpreters. I would uninstall it if possible, and install it using the official installer from python.org.

Comment: Currently facing the same thing. I've tried uninstalling the Homebrew python and the python version that came with the xcode-command-lines, with no avail.  Homebrew kept installing differing versions of Python as dependencies for other packages, so I tried to get them removed which resulted in this massive headache.

Answer (score 0):

You can try reinstalling Python 3.11 using Homebrew, and then make sure that the python3.11 executable and the pip3.11 executable are pointing to the same location by running which python3.11 and which pip3.11 commands.

Comment: Thanks you for answering, but I already did that. The locations of my executables are shown in the post above.